# Bioformats python module

Tags: python

The following python code:

```
import javabridge
import bioformats
javabridge.start_vm(class_path=bioformats.JARS)
```

gives this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Joshua\Documents\test.py", line 3, in 
    javabridge.start_vm(class_path=bioformats.JARS)
**AttributeError: module 'bioformats' has no attribute 'JARS'**

I'm not sure what is the issue. I believe I installed bioformats correctly...

Comment: Is it possible that you confused [`python-bioformats`](https://pypi.org/project/python-bioformats/) with the seemingly discontinued [`bioformats`](https://pypi.org/project/bioformats/) when installing; i.e did you do `pip install bioformats` instead of `pip install python-bioformats`?

Comment: Hmm it looks like I did make this mistake. So I uninstalled bioformats and installed python-bioformats. The problem remains...

Comment: It's hard to make definitive statements or even assumptions without further information. Do you have multiple Python interpreters installed? Did you remove bioformats and install python-bioformats in the same interpreter that you try to run the code in? Are you executing this in a Jupyter notebook and, if so, have you restarted that notebook after the installation?

Answer (score 0):

Exactly same problem, and I tried many ways including:

1. `pip install python-bioformats` in python3
2. conda install python-bioformats in python2

and none of them works.

Finally, the github version saved me: https://github.com/CellProfiler/python-bioformats. Download all of them, unzip, cd to your folder, and `python install python setup.py install` in your terminal.